# Angular storybook reference variables file stores in external repository

Tags: angular, cdn, storybook, angular-storybook

I want to import my variables file in the storybook which is currently stored in an external repository. I am referencing all my variables used in the storybook components from the external css variables file.

To resolve this I have referenced the external variables file by giving a relative path import in my bundles.scss file. In local while running the storybook, I'm using copy_cdn command before runni9ng my storybook local built command so that the variables file is copied into my storybook directory.
However, I want to avoid this method, when I run the build command. I want to reference these variables during runtime when the components are getting rendered.

**bundle.scss**

```
@import url("/cdn/styling/variables.css");
```

As an alternative I have created a preview-head.html file in .storybook folder,however in this way the reference variables are being shown as not defined

**preview-head.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cdn/styling/variables.css"/>
```

The challenge is if I reference the variables file in **preview.js** file then the build method is failing as it cannot get reference to that path